# is anchor link usage common in mobile based web design

Tags: navigation, mobile-web, scrolling

I'm working on a landing page with sections of content. Is it common to have anchor links on the top in mobile websites, when you click on the link you will jump to different section of the screen. while this is quite common in desktop would the same be user friendly on a mobile website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter for which device you are designing, the purpose remains same i.e. **In page navigation**. this makes your page more accessible to user hence it is user friendly regardless of the medium. you can find more about this in here [W3C-In-page Navigation.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/in-page-navigation/)

You can make this experience more clear and enjoyable in mobile by giving a smooth scroll animation perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to fit the navigation at the top of the web page of mobile. As in, stcking at the top of mobile screen may puch the information too far and down. Using anchor link in such scenario helps to navigate quickly over the mobile web page.

However, it can't said that the use of anchor link is common in mobile based web design. But, I know that anchor links helps users to get connected on same web page of the site. These anchor links are used to naviagte users through pager content. If any of the anchor link lets to get some information, then that particualr page may act as table of contents and even, give direct access to the interested topic.